# How to control the Mavic 2 pro using the Virtual Controller from Windows SDK

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I developed an application using DJI Windows SDK to control a Mavic 2 Pro. I manged to get all the data from the drone but when I tried to send commands to the drone through the VirtualRemoteController nothing happens

The set up is the following. I first send the command to auto-take off from my Windows app, which does it without out problems. Then, I give a position to move on my app. All the calculations are done as I expected but the drone  continues hovering despite the values that I am sending are different of 0 and are on the range [-1,1].

I am getting an instance of the virtual remote controller as it follows:

```cs
VirtualRemoteController virtualController = DJISDKManager.Instance.VirtualRemoteController;
```

Then, I use the following command to send the movement that I want to execute:

```cs
virtualController.UpdateJoystickValue(throttle,roll,pitch,yaw);
```

*throttle, roll, pitch and yaw* are values between [-1,1]

Answer (score 0):

This API is only supported for DJI aircraft that have a "WIFI-only" capability.

It is available for the Mavic Air for the Windows SDK.

The Mavic Pro supports Wifi but the Windows SDK does not support the Mavic Pro.

None of the Mavic 2 models support wifi.